# In places outside the US and Europe, how do I know if the standard is that one applies to a PhD program with a specific PhD advisor already in mind?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, united-states, europe

Suppose I want to apply to PhD programs at a university outside of the US and Europe.

How do I know if most universities there follow [what the US is doing or what Europe is doing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/43313/why-are-us-phds-different-from-european-phds)?

**Elaboration**: How do I know if most schools in the country/state want students to first apply to schools before choosing an doctoral advisor (like in the US) or to first contact the faculty members of a particular schools looking for a doctoral advisor before applying to said schools (like in Europe)?

Example: The UK [mostly](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42377/what-is-common-in-most-phd-application-procedures-in-the-uk) follows Europe. I heard Hong Kong and Japan follow the US.

Comment: It depends on program and scholarship, so this question makes not much sense as incredibly broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Find a school you want to apply to.

2) Email the graduate admissions contact person in the department.

3) In that email, ask politely.

4) Say thank you.

Comment: That's a bit harsh. :) It's not such a bad question as there could be country-specific conventions which I would be curious about.

Comment: also: read their website, you never know.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I am asking for most schools in a particular country/state. Asking 1 school in singapore doesn't tell me about the whole of Singapore

Comment: @gnometorule EXACTLY

Comment: But you are not applying to the whole of Singapore.

Comment: @Jack it does if you ask about the general practice in that country as well as the practice of a particular school.

Comment: @BSteinhurst Okay fine. This answers my question. Sorry I was an asshole. Thanks :) http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v642/shakespeares_sister/apix/twd5-3.jpg

Answer (score 1):

In the US, you would look at a department's website for instructions for how to apply to grad school in that department, and then follow those instructions. The nature of those instructions will let you know whether that school follows the US model or the European model.

Comment: My question is not about particular schools. Of course I can always find out by contacting, but what about most schools in a particular country/state?

Comment: There's no consistent list of this stuff, so unless you have particular countries you're interested in, we're not going to be able to put every other country in the world into one bin or the other for you.

Comment: Bill Barth Okay fine. This answers my question. Sorry I was an asshole. Thanks :) http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v642/shakespeares_sister/apix/twd5-3.jpg